# How to Get total and Current Slide Number of Carousel in Bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello guys i want to get current slide number of carousel in bootstrap 3.3.4 i already used this script in below 3 version and work perfectly but in version 3.3.4 not working any one help me out of this situation 
thnx in advance
code which is use

```js
var totalItems = $('.item').length;
var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
$('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');

$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
});

$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {
    currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
   $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');
});
```

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.num{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="well span9 columns">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div> 
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="num"></div>
```

but when i used in version 3.3.4 it did not working please please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
   $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');
});
```

Comment: thnx buddy, can you help me little bit more, currently it start with  /3 and on next slide it show 1/3 and on last slide it show 2/3 but i want it start from 1/3 and at last slide it show 3/3 plx help me for this problem

Comment: Sure I can help you but didn't get the issue. When I run code snippet, it starts with 1/3 and the last one already 3/3. Am i wrong?

Comment: yes you r right it start from 1/3 and end at 3/3 but this works in my code snippet and it run on version 3.0.0 but when i run your script at version 3.3.4 it starts from /3 and end at 2/3, can you show me your script at code snippet.

Comment: You're welcome.. Please don't forget the vote :) thanks

Comment: Actually, 'slide.bs.carousel' is working before slide start but 'slid.bs.carousel' after finishing slide.